# Determining two most similar objects based on multiple variables

Tags: anova, t-test, dataset, least-squares

I am trying to determine the two most similar years based on a number of environmentally variables. For example, I would like to choose the most similar year to 2015, from the set 1989 to 2016, based on monthly temperature, precip, solar radiation, and soil temperature.

There are 12 observations of every variable for each year.

I am not sure what statistical test to run to determine this. I am attempting to do this analysis in R. I believe that the best way to do this is analysis of variation (ANOVA) but I am not sure that it is correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *Similarity* is usually defined as proximity according to some measure of distance. There would be no "statistical test... to determine" that; you need to define the distance measure appropriate for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how one would approach this with hypothesis-testing.

Some simple metrics (that is, measures of distance) are Euclidean distance (the square root of the sum of squared differences on each feature) and taxicab distance (the sum of the absolute differences). You would probably want to normalize each feature first so that distances are unaffected by the different scales of the features. For any given object, you can find the most similar one by computing its distance from every other object and choosing the object that minimizes the distance.

This said, I have no idea what real problem you're trying to solve by finding similar years, and hence no idea if this process will be useful to you.